# Stricter String.format that does not ignore extra arguments?

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

Java's `String.format` silently ignores extra arguments passed that are not used in format string but fails if less or invalid ones are passed. Is there a way to handle the case when more arguments are passed ?

> If there are more arguments than format specifiers, the extra arguments are ignored

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-

```
private static void doStuff(Stuff stuff, String details, Object... args) {
    if(stuff.someCondition()) {
        try {
            details = String.format("Details: " + details, args);
        } catch (Exception ex) { //No Exception thrown when args are not used by
            String arguments = Arrays.stream(args)
                    .map(Objects::toString)
                    .collect(joining(";"));
            details = String.format("Details: %s Args: %s", details, arguments);
        }
    }
    stuff.process(details);
}

private static void foo() {
    Stuff stuff = new Stuff();
    doStuff(stuff, "blah blah %s ", "blah"); // No exception, works as expected
    doStuff(stuff, "blah blah %s %s", "blah"); // Fails as expected and args are printed
    doStuff(stuff, "blah blah %s", "blah", "blah"); // Silently ignores. How to handle this case?
}
```

Comment: can you show us which case you want to handle?

Comment: @YCF_L Added example

Comment: What would you like done with the extra arguments?

Comment: You can simply count the instances of substrings beginning with %, exclude %%, and check if the resulting number matches the length of the arguments

Comment: @mypetlion print in a different way as shown in example.

Comment: It's not a simple problem. Consider this: `String.format("%1$s %1$s", 1, 2)`. Should it fail because `2` is unused? What about `String.format("%2$s", 1, 2)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a different approach without counting or parsing for `%`. Not an efficient one though.

```
public static String safeFormat(String formatStr, Object... args) {
    List<Object> objects = Arrays.asList(args);
    // https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.7/org/apache/commons/lang3/mutable/MutableBoolean.html
    MutableBoolean isCalled = new MutableBoolean(false);
    objects.add(new Object(){
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            isCalled.setTrue();
            return "";
        }
    });
    String result = String.format(formatStr+"%s", objects.toArray());
    if(isCalled.isFalse()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not all arguments used by formatter");
    }

    return result;
}
```